# ASP.Net Core Returning from action filter

Tags: asp.net-core, actionfilterattribute

I need to apply a filter to the request. I created a subclass of `ActionFilterAttribute` with overrided `OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)`. I have a bit sophisticated logic inside the filter and in some cases I must stop the running of the filter and return default action result (as if there were no filter). If I `return` in the filter, workflow seems to stop completely, no action result returns. I tried to `await next()` or call `base.OnActionExecutionAsync(...)`, but that didn't work. How can I implement returning from filter?
I have something like this:

```
    public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        //some logic

        if (questionnaireId == Guid.Empty)
        {
            //here I need to let the  mvc action run normally
            return;//it doesn't work
        } else {
            //some logic..
        }            
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your code ? And why do you want to implement an `ActionFilter`, may be a `middleware` is a best choice

Comment: @aguafrommars I doubt about a middleware because my logic deals with MVC only and I wouldn't like to add one more handler in pipeline for the whole app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for returning default result add `await base.OnActionExecutionAsync(context, next)`;

```
public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
{
    //some logic

    if (questionnaireId == Guid.Empty)
        await base.OnActionExecutionAsync(context, next);
    else {
        //some logic..
    }
}
```